# rqt_action: command not found

Tags: ros, rqt

I need to use rqt_aciton tool to monitor an action communication but when I run `rqt_action` I got this error message.
I've tried `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-rqt-action` it told me that `ros-noetic-rqt-action is already the newest version (0.4.9-1focal.20230215.222247)`.
Also tried `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`, it didn't work neither.
I even downloaded the source code in [github](https://github.com/ros/actionlib.git) and compiled it, source it, problem was still there. Besides, `rosrun actionlib axclient.py` was also dead.

Comment: Try to open `rqt` and check the menu bar if this plugin is available.

Comment: I found that script axclient.py, and some other scripts were in the actionlib_tools package, so I installed `actionlib_tools` and ran `rosrun actionlib_tools axclient.py`, problem solved.